# date and time is not inserted in my sql database

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, phpmyadmin, sql-insert

I am inserting datetime object in mysql database, query does not execute. ie no insertion takes place. where as data type of current_time and expiry_time in db is datetime. here is my code. kindly specify my mistake. i shall be very thankful.

```
if($timespan == '3 days') {$expiry_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+3 days'));}
if($timespan == '5 days') {$expiry_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+5 days'));}
if($timespan == '7 days') {$expiry_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+7 days'));}

$dt = new DateTime();
$dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$dt = serialize($dt);
$sql="INSERT INTO survey (user, title, description, opta, optb,optc,optd,uploaded,current_time,expiry_time) VALUES ('$user','$title', '$dis', '$a' , '$b', '$c', '$d','','$dt','$expiry_time')";
if (mysqli_query($con,$sql))
 {
  echo "Success";
 }
 else
  {
  echo "Error: " . mysql_error();
  }
```

Comment: what is the datatype for `current_time` ?

Comment: Do you get an exception?

Comment: Is there a reason you're serializing $dt?

Comment: Why are you serializing $dt?

Comment: Why not `$expiry_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+' . $timespan));` ?

Comment: i don't get any exception. datatype of current_time and expiry time is datetime in db

Comment: So if your query fails, what does `mysql_error()` print out?

Comment: it prints success, but no insertion takes place

Comment: Are you sure you're looking into the correct table? There is not way the insert is failing if you're seeing "Success" being printed on screen

Answer (score 2):

Because `$dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');` returns a string and does not convert the `$dt` DateTime object to a string. Save the output of `$dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');` to a variable and insert that.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `mysql NOW()`

```
$sql="INSERT INTO survey (user, title, description, opta, optb,optc,optd,uploaded,current_time,expiry_time) VALUES ('$user','$title', '$dis', '$a' , '$b', '$c', '$d','',NOW(),'$expiry_time')";
```